Binary Classification on Deep Learning Models always returns one label only
I am trying to build a Deep Learning Model with GRU / LSTM for binary classification with Word2Vec word embeddings. But it only predicts one label from the test set, however the I can train regular Machine Learning Model (Random Forest Classifier) with the same data succesfully.
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, GRU, Dropout, Input
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import Constant

# Defining Neural Network for GRU
model_gru = Sequential(name="Word2Vec_GRU")

# Input layer
model_gru.add(Input(shape=(max_length,), name="input"))

# Add the embedding layer to the model
model_gru.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, 
                        output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, 
                        trainable=False, 
                        embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_vectors)))

# GRU
model_gru.add(GRU(units=128))
model_gru.add(Dropout(0.1))
model_gru.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model_gru.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_gru.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model_gru.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), 
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

model_gru.summary()

GRU Architecture
The LSTM models share the same architecture as this GRU model I created. When I train the model, the validation accuracy did not improve within the 10 epochs.
history = model_gru.fit(X_train, 
                        y_train, 
                        epochs=10,
                        validation_split=0.1,
                        validation_steps=1,
                        batch_size=32)

Epoch 1/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7s 60ms/step - accuracy: 0.8753 - loss: 0.5219 - val_accuracy: 0.9062 - val_loss: 0.3934
Epoch 2/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7s 62ms/step - accuracy: 0.8858 - loss: 0.4044 - val_accuracy: 0.8438 - val_loss: 0.4354
Epoch 3/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7s 61ms/step - accuracy: 0.8790 - loss: 0.3827 - val_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.1612
Epoch 4/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10s 64ms/step - accuracy: 0.8772 - loss: 0.3775 - val_accuracy: 0.8438 - val_loss: 0.4349
Epoch 5/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10s 63ms/step - accuracy: 0.8851 - loss: 0.3607 - val_accuracy: 0.8125 - val_loss: 0.4953
Epoch 6/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 11s 67ms/step - accuracy: 0.8764 - loss: 0.3784 - val_accuracy: 0.9688 - val_loss: 0.1979
Epoch 7/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8s 67ms/step - accuracy: 0.8724 - loss: 0.3897 - val_accuracy: 0.8438 - val_loss: 0.4367
Epoch 8/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8s 66ms/step - accuracy: 0.8702 - loss: 0.3920 - val_accuracy: 0.9375 - val_loss: 0.2562
Epoch 9/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7s 60ms/step - accuracy: 0.8769 - loss: 0.3761 - val_accuracy: 0.9688 - val_loss: 0.1962
Epoch 10/10
116/116 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10s 61ms/step - accuracy: 0.8727 - loss: 0.3829 - val_accuracy: 0.9375 - val_loss: 0.2554

This resulting the model only returns 0 as the predicted label, with evaluation function here:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def evaluate_model(model, X_test, y_test):
    y_pred_prob = model.predict(X_test)
    
    # Predict result to 1 (spam) if probability > 0.5
    y_pred = (np.round(y_pred_prob))
    
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, zero_division=0)
    recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, zero_division=0)
    f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, zero_division=0)
    
    # Print metrics
    print("\nAccuracy:", accuracy)
    print("Precision:", precision)
    print("Recall:", recall)
    print("F1-Score:", f1)
    
    # Print classification report
    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, zero_division=0))
    
    # Confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cmap='Blues', fmt='g', cbar=False)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted labels')
    plt.ylabel('True labels')
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
    plt.show()

GRU Evaluation Result
I tried to undersampled and oversampled the training set, but the metrics on the testing process becomes abstract and near zero:
# Oversampling the minority class in X_train
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from collections import Counter

oversample = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='majority')
X_train_sampled, y_train_over = oversample.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
print(Counter(y_train_over))

Training GRU with sampled data
Although the predicted labels on test set returns the same like before as it also predict the label as 0 only.
However, if I tried to run the training with Machine Learning approach such as Random Forest classifier, it can return the correct label better, even though it doesn't go through the sampling process.
Random Forest Classifier without Sampling Result
This makes me draw the conclusion that I think the training & test data do not yields a problem that I really worry about.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Did I make my model wrong, or the evaluation function is wrong? Or I should tweak any of the parameters? If so, how? Or is it the data? I have been scratching my head for hours. Any helps are appreciated. Thank you!
My complete experiment can be found on kaggle
